# Working with subviews on iPad

Tags: iphone

How are subviews created/arranged and managed on iPad?

If there is a main view controller that needs subviews. How are these views created and added to the view? Giving them positions within the main view.

Comment: This is an extremely vague question.  Do you mean "how do I create vies and add them in code?" or do you mean "how do I set up the view hierarchy in IB?" or do you mean something else?

Comment: IB or in the code. I would like to create a number of subviews. which I could either fill with tableviews. imageviews, scrollviews etc. I would like to place the views where I want. I dont mind if it is done in IB or in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each app usually has one UIWindow.

You can add subviews to that UIWindow.  Most of the built in projects (like tab or split based) do that for you.